# Select on 2 tables return no result?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables :

Table 'annonce' (real estate ads) :

```
idAnnonce  |  reference
-----------------------
1          |  dupond
2          |  toto
```

Table 'freeDays' (Free days for all ads) :

```
idAnnonce  |  date
-----------------------
1          |  2015-06-06
1          |  2015-06-07
1          |  2015-06-09
1          |  2015-06-10
2          |  2015-06-06
2          |  2015-06-07
2          |  2015-06-12
2          |  2015-06-13
```

I want to select all alvailable ads who have only free days between a start and end date, I have to check each days between this date.

The request :

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
        `annonce`.`idAnnonce`, `annonce`.`reference` 
    FROM
        `annonce`, `freeDays` 
    WHERE
        `annonce`.`idAnnonce` = `freeDays`.`idAnnonce`
    AND
        `freeDays`.`date` = '2015-06-06'
    AND
        `freeDays`.`date` = '2015-06-07'
```

Return no result. Where is my error ?

Comment: ...and `freeDays`.`date` IN ('2015-06-06', '2015-06-07')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It cant be equal both dates

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.idAnnonce, a.reference 
FROM annonce a 
INNER JOIN freeDays f ON a.idAnnonce = f.idAnnonce
WHERE f.date BETWEEN '2015-06-06' AND '2015-06-07'
```

Comment: Thank's but if I have a "hole" between the 2 dates :
2015-06-06 ; 2015-06-07 ; 2015-06-09. the ads will be selected ?

Comment: soory, wrong manipulation :  if I have a "hole" between the 2 dates : 2015-06-06 ; 2015-06-07 ; 2015-06-09. the ads will be selected ?

Comment: @Greg3030 then you would use the first and the last date e.g. `BETWEEN 2015-06-06 AND 2015-06-09`

Comment: Yes understood that. But in this intervale, one day missing. So I dont want this idAnnonce being select. Maybe I should create new question, more spécific. Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

What Matt is say is correct. You can also do this as alternative:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.idAnnonce, a.reference 
FROM annonce a 
INNER JOIN freeDays f ON a.idAnnonce = f.idAnnonce
WHERE f.date IN('2015-06-06','2015-06-07')
```

Or like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.idAnnonce, a.reference 
FROM annonce a 
INNER JOIN freeDays f ON a.idAnnonce = f.idAnnonce
WHERE f.date ='2015-06-06' OR f.date ='2015-06-07'
```

This will give you the same result as with an `BETWEEN`

Comment: Absolutely, there all possible solutions, i only went with BETWEEN as in the question they stated "only free days between a start and end date" which led me to believe this could be requiring a range rather than specific dates

Comment: @Matt : Just giving alternative for the problem that the OP has. Your answer is the preferred one

Answer (score 0):

Your WHERE clause is asking for the impossible!

You are asking for rows where the 'freedays'.'date' value is both 2015-06-06 *and* 2015-06-07.

```
AND
    freeDays.date = '2015-06-06'
AND
    freeDays.date = '2015-06-07'
```

You need to use BETWEEN:

```
freeDays.date BETWEEN '2015-06-06' AND '2015-06-07'

AND
    freeDays.date = '2015-06-06'
OR
    freeDays.date = '2015-06-07'
```